# Adding a CollectionViewController as a subView

Tags: swift, scrollview, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview, childviewcontroller

Using Swift 5.1.3, iOS13.3, XCode11.3,

I try to display a horizontal collectionView that is wider than the view's width.
By dragging, the collectionView cells shall scroll horizontally.

The problem now is the following: As soon as I click to drag, the collectionView content "disappears" (i.e. turns transparent). If you look carefully, you can see that the scrollbar is still there.

Why is does the collectionView content turns transparent as soon as I click into it ?

Here is a video illustrating the error behaviour:

Below you will find the corresponding code:

[image]

Here is the code:

Inside my Main-ViewController I add the collectionView:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let cardsHorizontalController = CardsHorizontalController() 

    self.view.addSubview(cardsHorizontalController.view)

    cardsHorizontalController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cardsHorizontalController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 100.0).isActive = true
    cardsHorizontalController.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 279).isActive = true
    cardsHorizontalController.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width).isActive = true
}
```

Here is the collectionView controller class:

```
class CardsHorizontalController: BaseListController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    let cellId = "cellId"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear

        collectionView.register(CardHeaderCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

        if let layout = collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        }

        collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 100, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return .init(width: view.frame.width - 48, height: view.frame.height)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return .init(top: 0, left: 16, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }

}
```

And its corresponding parent class:

```
class BaseListController: UICollectionViewController {

    init() {
        super.init(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

And here the collectionView cell at play:

```
class CardHeaderCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    let imageView = UIImageView(cornerRadius: 8)

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        imageView.backgroundColor = .red

        let stackView = VerticalStackView(arrangedSubviews: [
            // companyLabel,
            // titleLabel,
            imageView
            ], spacing: 12)
        addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.fillSuperview(padding: .init(top: 16, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0))
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }

}
```

Comment: If you use Xcode's View Debugging after the content vanishes, does it give hints?  Unexpected size, location, color, constraints, z-order?

Comment: @Philip:  I tried to use the View-Debugging as you suggested. It shows the view hierarchies. However, as for the collectionView, only the scrollbar is visible. The rest of the red collectionView is nowhere in the view hierarchy. It seems transparent. And the only superview of the visible scrollView is a `UICollectionViewControllerWrapperView` - again with no content (or transparent content)

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution:

The collectionView-Controller (i.e. `CardsHorizontalController()`) needs to be added as a **ChildController**!

Inside Main-ViewController's `viewDidLoad()`(in first paragraph of code above), please replace the following line...

```
self.view.addSubview(cardsHorizontalController.view)
```

with the following:

```
self.addChild(cardsHorizontalController)
self.view.addSubview(cardsHorizontalController.view)
self.didMove(toParent: cardsHorizontalController)
```

Having done so, everything works as expected !

You find a working project (stripped-down with only the CollectionView) in this GitHub repo: https://github.com/iKK001/HorizontalCollectionViewExample

And since I'm so happy - here a video of the working horizontal CollectionView:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing `return .init(width: view.frame.width - 48, height: view.frame.height)` inside `sizeForItemAt` to `return .init(width: collectionView.frame.width - 48, height: collectionView.frame.height)`?

Comment: yes, I just tried. But no change ! still transparent when clicked... Any other ideas ?  Could it be that I need to place a childviewcontroller of some sort instead of a subview adding ??